# React fetch give error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6

[image]This API works in Postman but when I apply it to my program it's give errors

```
method: "POST",

'Accept': 'application/json',

'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
```

gives  415 (Unsupported Media Type)

also I tried 'Content-type' : 'application/json' (its give cors error http://localhost:3000/) and many

please help

Thanks

Comment: `its give cors error` - does the API issue CORS headers in the response? If not, then you can't access the API directly from the browser

Comment: When you are requesting to server API you should specify the content type appropriately. Are you running the program from the same domain(host and port) as the requested API? If not then you have to explicitly allow the domain from the API.

Comment: this is the Cors error : from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: what is the server you are using, you have to whitelist the localhost domain from the server, inorder to resolve the CORS issue

Comment: CORS you get because it's other origin, your API and React webapp are on other ports. if your API is in Node, then you need to install `cors()` and add it as middleware, if you use express, then you need to add `app.use(cors())`

Comment: API is not in Node @Dominik Matis

Comment: @SahanS please clarify how and where (host, port, directly file) you are running the client and server. As I have (and many others) mentioned already perhaps you are facing CORS issue imposed by browsers (Postman and other clients don't care) and you have to handle that from the target API. Once you clarify we can provide a definite solution.

Comment: @fiveelements this is the CORS ERROR 'http://192.168.200.135:8080/api-proxy/anonymous/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: If you want this to work for testing purpose you may try disabling CORS in the browser. Otherwise, you have to set certain headers from the server-side (API): `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. Depending on the technology used to implement the API, you have to set these headers in the response in the appropriate way. Minimally you may just do `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to allow the API calls from any domain.

Comment: @ fiveelements Thanks yes it is works after disable CORS in chrome browser. I think it will okay after edit the server side.
Disable CORS Chrome Reference : https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: @ fiveelements from server side I already added
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, authorization,
But Still I have Issue.